# Triangle Type Program

Tags: java

Is there any way to simplify it further?

```
import java.util.*;

class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();


        if(a==b && b==c)
            System.out.println("Equilateral");

        else if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c) )
            System.out.println("Not a triangle");

        else if ((a==b && b!=c ) || (a!=b && c==a) || (c==b && c!=a))
            System.out.println("Isosceles");

        else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a)
            System.out.println("Scalene");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any way to simplify it further?

Sure, but what's more important: Create some useful methods. Your class is single shot only: read data, classify, output. This is a bad start, a method should do one thing only. So you need three methods.

You classify into 4 categories and this is a clear case for an enum:

```
enum TriangleType {
    EQUILATERAL, INVALID, ISOSCELES, SCALENE
}
```

This is the only interesting method:

```
static TriangleType classify(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0) return INVALID; // added test
    if (a == b && b == c) return EQUILATERAL;
    if (a >= b+c || c >= b+a || b >= a+c) return INVALID;
    if (b==c || a==b || c==a)) return ISOSCELES;
    return SCALENE;
}
```

Note that I'm violating the "braces everywhere" rule. I can't help myself.

In case of `ISOSCELES`, there's no need for checks like `a==b && b!=c` as we already know that not all sites are equal.

In case of `SCALENE`, there's no need for any test, as we know that there are no two equals sides.

---

You're using a bit too many parentheses, but feel free to keep them if you feel you need them.

Be consequent with your spacing, there are rules for it, which help to make it more readable:

- single space between "if" and "("
- (but no space between a method name and "(")
- no space after "("
- no space before ")"

---

The addition is subject to overflow as Ryan noted, but let's ignore it for now. You should know about it and do a corresponding test if needed, but in general, overflow is impossible to check for everywhere.

Here it's trivial, just replace `a >= b+c` by `a >= (long) b+c`. The latter means `a >= ((long) b) + c`, which is equivalent to `((long) a) >= ((long) b) + ((long) c)`.

Comment: Not sure if it is a problem, but one of the sums (i.e. `a+b`) may cause an integer overflow, which does not give `INVALID`.

Comment: @Ryan If the OP is using Java 8, the overflow can be handled using the new `Math.addExact()` method which would throw an `ArithmeticException` in the presence of overflows.

Comment: Do you know about the performance of `Math.addExact(int, int)`? I cannot seem to find anything on it. For the lazy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int- (regarding @EdwinDalorzo's comment)

Comment: @Ryan Here's the link: [Math.addExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-). You can read the JDK 8 source code for performance. I am sure that'll not be an issue. You'll see implementation is quite simple and straightforward. You could even do it with JDK 7 by implementing the same logic.

Comment: @Ryan I guess, the performance is fine in case the exception gets rarely thrown (just a predicted branch, costs 0 or 1 cycle on common HW as it can execute in parallel with other operations). If it throws, then it takes long, and if it throws often, then the branch gets hard to predict and performance  suffers. I would not use it except when the exception is the wanted outcome (and occurs exceptionally only). If you want just a safer check, then see my update.

Answer (score 3):

as an addition to all already mentioned points:

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> ```
>
> **This is dumb!**

The Java Util-Package contains a [large amount of classes, interfaces and exceptions.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) With that single line, you make Eclipse / Netbeans "Do what I want Button" (tm) - *also known as "completion suggestion"* - load **ALL THE CLASSES**:

> [image: how not to do it]

What exactly do you use of that? right, the `Scanner`.
Aside from being hugely inconvenient, it clutters your namespace and can lead to naming conflicts.

Instead do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Additional "nitpicks:"

- Place braces around if and else blocks...
- Make your variable names more speaking than `a, b, c`, even though it's hard with triangle-sides
- Improve User Experience (UX). If someone executes this, what are they supposed to enter??

Comment: I strongly doubt that all the classes get loaded!

Comment: @maaartinus hmm... possibly. The IDE's "Do what I want button"(tm) actually loads all the **** you got there, though. Additionally I think that (while the classes may not actually be "loaded"), they are loaded into the runtime constant pool, which consumes memory..

Comment: I doubt the constant pool, too. The imports are a source only feature and the constant pool contains FQNs only. I guess every compiler emits only needed constants.

Comment: @maaartinus isn't the wildcard import just a shorthand for specifying all FQNs at once? At least I understood it that way... How else would wildcard imports actually work without throwing LinkageErrors to infinity?

Comment: AFAIK it's only syntactic sugar. Something the compiler uses (for replacing all simple names by FQNs) and forgets at the very beginning. If it sees `java.util.*` it resolves e.g., `List` against it (assuming no conflicts), but that's all.

Comment: I have tested by writing 2 identical java code, one uses import `*` and the other specify the class to import, and run both with `java -verbose` option. The outputs from both cases are identical (except for the class it is run). I have confirmed it on Java 1.6.0_20-b02 and Java 1.7.0_60-b19. Therefore, I think your claim that import `*` imports all classes is **invalid**. I haven't confirmed whether the bytecode is identical, but I really doubt there would be any difference (apart from class name).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @nhahtdh I have already edited my answer accordingly 14 hours ago (as of now). I must insist that completion suggestions **does** load all these classes, or at least their "headers" though.

Comment: @Vogel612: Please use "completion suggestion" rather than "Do what I want button" - it is at best confusing. And I think the IDE would just load everything (or it does something smart) regardless of your imports.

Comment: @nhahtdh no it definitely doesn't. I was actually thinking the "Do what I want button" was more speaking than "completion suggestion", but alas. Will edit now.

Comment: @Vogel612: Is there any source to your claim? If you type a letter and use the completion suggestion, it should load everything that is in the classpath so that it can give all possible suggestion to you, no?

Comment: @nhahtdh I'd say you should back that one up, because quite frankly *"everything in the classpath"* at least on the project I am working on is a sh*tload of stuff. And most of that doesn't show up anywhere. From my experience until now, you need to have the type imported to have it show up in the completion suggestions. At least in eclipse that is..

Comment: @Vogel612: Except for the cases where there are too few character, where you are right that Eclipse doesn't show everything (since it would be useless to user anyway), if you type more character (about 4-5), it will show things that you haven't even import, and if you select it, it will auto import for you. So either it loads everything, or it does something smart, and it does so regardless of the import, well, that is for the case when there are a bit more characters.

Comment: Classes don't get loaded when they are imported, they are loaded when they are first use. See [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) about When Class Initialization Occurs.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo would you mind reading the comment thread for a little? Additionally I hope you do realize that `initialization != loading`. As an aside I do not claim that the classes are loaded into the runtime / constant-pool but they are loaded and preferred by the "autocomplete" (or whatever you call it) that your IDE most probably allows.

Comment: You still haven't proven that the IDE actually loads less when import are specified. The fact that the IDE shows only those from the imports when there are few character is likely due to UX. Since you claim it to be so, you should be the one who backs up your claim. If your content is challenged and you can't back it up, it should be edited out.

Comment: @nhahtdh accepted. Upon further research it seems that the processor works mostly with analyzing the strings, but I haven't been able to get exact information yet. For more info see the [eclipse wiki faq related entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_language_editor%3F)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of redundancy due to symmetry, since `a`, `b`, and `c` are interchangeable.  Whenever you have a group of variables that should be treated the same way as each other, you should consider using an array instead.

Once you [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29) the sides by length, the problem becomes easier.  Need to check for a negative length (which you didn't do)?  Just check the smallest number.  Need to detect an equilateral triangle?  Just check the "shortest" and "longest" sides for equality.

In one of the comments, @Ryan pointed out that adding two sides could result in overflow.  Therefore, subtracting is safer.

```
int[] s = new int[3];   // Lengths of the sides
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(s);

    if (s[0] <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Side with non-positive length");
    }

    System.out.println( (s[0] == s[2]) ? "Equilateral"
                      : (s[2] - s[1] >= s[0]) ? "Not a triangle" 
                      : (s[1] == s[0] || s[1] == s[2]) ? "Isosceles"
                      : "Scalene");
}
```

Comment: TBH I find the approach OP is taking far more obvious and easy to understand.. Additionally IMO there *must* be a special place in hell for people who nest ternary statements, but eh.

Comment: Why the downvote? Unless I'm getting really rusty with high-school trigonometry, sorting the sides first does simplify the comparison as shown in the code. I guess it boils down to trading any significant performance hits for `Arrays.sort()` for simpler `if`-comparisons?

Comment: @h.j.k. I downvoted for the loss in obviousness of what the if statements actually do, and how they internally work.

Comment: @Vogel612, after sorting: if the shortest and longest sides are the same, it's an equilateral triangle. If the longest side is greater than the sum of two other sides (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), it's not a triangle. If any two sides are the same (after checking for equilateral triangle), it's an isosceles triangle. Otherwise, default to scalene triangle.

Comment: @Vogel612 Ternary chaining works perfectly well in every language except PHP. I think that the usage above is almost English-like in readability. Shortest side equals longest side? Equilateral. Difference between the two longest sides exceeds the shortest side? Not a triangle. Two equal sides? Isosceles. Otherwise, scalene.

Comment: @It's not about the problems of ternary chaining or the correctness of the results. It's about the obviousness in approaching the problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for strictly fewer lines, this is what I submitted to a competition with that problem. It really only reduces it by a couple lines, and it's not quite as simple as `if` `else` statements, but I think it might work better for larger input.

```
import java.util.*;
public class triangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer[] sides = {in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(), in.nextInt()};
    Arrays.sort(sides);
    if(sides[0] + sides[1] < sides[2])
        System.out.println("NOT A TRIANGLE");
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<>();
    for(Integer i : sides)
        occurences.put(i, occurences.get(i) == null ? 1 : occurences.get(i) + 1);
    int size = occurences.size();
    System.out.println(size == 3 ? "Scalene" : (size == 2 ? "Isocoles" : "Equilateral"));
    }
}
```