# Modeling a Triangle, with a utility method to classify it

Tags: java, rags-to-riches

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62891/triangle-type-program), I played a bit with the idea of modeling a Triangle, and a utility method to classify it:

```
class Triangle {

    private final int a;
    private final int b;
    private final int c;

    enum Type {
        EQUILATERAL, INVALID, ISOSCELES, SCALENE
    }

    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (!isSaneArguments(a, b, c)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("All sides of a Triangle must be > 0");
        }
        if (!isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a triangle: no side must be longer than the sum of the other sides");
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    private static boolean isSaneArguments(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0;
    }

    private static boolean isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b;
    }

    public static Type classifyValidTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        final Type type;
        if (a == b && b == c) {
            type = Type.EQUILATERAL;
        } else if (b == c || a == b || c == a) {
            type = Type.ISOSCELES;
        } else {
            type = Type.SCALENE;
        }
        return type;
    }

    public static Type classify(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (!isSaneArguments(a, b, c) || !isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
            return Type.INVALID;
        }
        return classifyValidTriangle(a, b, c);
    }

    public Type classify() {
        return classifyValidTriangle(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
public class TriangleTest {
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testInvalidTriangleWithTooLongSide() {
        int a = 1;
        int b = a + 1;
        new Triangle(a, b, a + b + 1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testInvalidTriangleWithNegativeSide() {
        new Triangle(1, 2, 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testScalene() {
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.SCALENE, new Triangle(2, 3, 4).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.SCALENE, Triangle.classify(2, 3, 4));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquilateral() {
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.EQUILATERAL, new Triangle(3, 3, 3).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.EQUILATERAL, new Triangle(2, 2, 2).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.EQUILATERAL, Triangle.classify(5, 5, 5));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsosceles() {
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, new Triangle(3, 3, 2).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, new Triangle(3, 2, 3).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, new Triangle(2, 3, 3).classify());
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, Triangle.classify(2, 3, 3));
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, Triangle.classify(3, 3, 2));
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, Triangle.classify(3, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

What do you think? What would you do differently? How can it be better?

Comment: Both `classifyValidTriangle` and `classify` are public, that's strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would restructure the `Triangle` class as follows

```
public class Triangle {

    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        // validation and instantiation
    }

    public static enum Type {
        EQUILATERAL {
            @Override
            boolean matches(Triangle t) {
                // check if the given triangle matches this type
            }
        },
        ISOSCELES {
            @Override
            boolean matches(Triangle t) {
                // check if the given triangle matches this type
            }
        },
        SCALENE {
            @Override
            boolean matches(Triangle t) {
                // check if the given triangle matches this type
            }
        };

        private static Type classify(Triangle t) {
            for (Type type : values()) {
                if (type.matches(t)) {
                    return type;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        abstract boolean matches(Triangle t);
    }

    public Type getType() {
        try {
            return Type.classify(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Some points to note

1. The constructor should carry out all the validations so that once you get a `Triangle` object you have a valid triangle to work with
2. If you have a valid triangle there is no reason to keep the `Type.INVALID` type
3. The triangle classification logic is put into the `Type` enum itself for a better encapsulation
4. When uncertain I tend to make the access modifiers as private as possible

Comment: Excellent points, I like this!

Comment: `IllegalStateException` must be IAE.

Comment: @maaartinus you're absolutely right, updated my answer.

Comment: -1: If `a == b && b == c` then `EQUILATERAL`. They have three equal sides. First point about classification logic invalid.
Second point is flawed, you're not dealing with points. You're dealing with side lengths.
Third point is only valid if you don't use else-if... which is only necessary with your re-write. Not a very strong point either.

Comment: @Pimgd, you're right too. That was silly of me to make that false assumption. Sorry to confuse every one. Will remove those points from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pick a model, and stick with it. You have duplicated much of your logic at the static level and the instance level. Specific cases are the `classify()` instance method, and the `classify(int,int,int)` static method. There is no need for both.

Additionally, the logic split between the two validation methods `isSaneArguments` and `isTriangle` should all be in one method (I recommend `isTriangle`). There is no place you call them separately, so there is no reason to split them. `isSaneArguments` is a poor name anyway.... Finally, it's not exactly 'yoda conditions', but I prefer to do calculations on the left-side of a comparison operator like `<` or `>`. Bracing them makes it more readable in a chain of arguments...:

```
isTriangle(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
    // positive lengths, and sides that can meet
    return a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0  && (a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) > a;
}
```

The way your class is laid out lends itself to having static calls to get the properties of the triangles. It appears that the class is designed to regularly encounter invalid triangles, (hence `Type.INVALID`), so having a constructor throw an exception is unpleasant. I would make the constructor private, and do the validation outside the constructor, and would keep the methods static...

Note, classifyValidTriangle is public, but does no validation, (like the name says), this is odd.... to trust the caller that much. I would still expect validation of arguments, and an IllegalArgumentException if they are not met.

The classify method would also be better if written as an early-return mechanism, instead of holding the `type` variable....

Note that the actual Triangle instance does not do much, and there is no apparent purpose for it.

Neither your class, nor the embedded enum are public, this seems odd.

Finally, I rearranged the code to put the enum at the top, the static methods next, then the fields, and constructor:

```
public class Triangle {

    public enum Type {
        EQUILATERAL, INVALID, ISOSCELES, SCALENE
    }

    public static Triangle buildTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
            return new Triangle(a, b, c);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input values are not able to make a triangle");
    }

    public static Type classify(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (!isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
            return Type.INVALID;
        }
        if (a == b && b == c) {
            return Type.EQUILATERAL;
        }
        if (b == c || a == b || c == a) {
            return Type.ISOSCELES;
        }
        return Type.SCALENE;
    }

    private static boolean isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        // positive lengths, and sides that can meet
        return a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0  && (a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) > a;
    }

    private final int a;
    private final int b;
    private final int c;

    private Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! Good points, I agree with most of it. About early returns, I agree, but I have a bit of a dilemma: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/256301/early-return-statements-and-cyclomatic-complexity About rearranging the code, your suggestion doesn't conform to the recommendation of checkstyle: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#DeclarationOrder (and probably JLS too, but I can't find the right link now)

Comment: Putting the fields in the middle is IMHO bad as it makes them really hard to find. Some put it on the top just after the inner classes but this makes them also a bit hard to find. So I put them at the bottom. ;) I guess, there are as many styles as people.

Comment: I really disagree with all your comments (there's just one). It shows that it should be written differently (maybe `boolean positiveLengths = ...; if (!positiveLengths) return false; ...`).

Comment: -1: Contains bugs and false advice. In trying to simplify the boolean conditions you added a bug that renders any valid triangle to be not a triangle. I wouldn't have combined both methods at all precisely for the complications this may cause.

Comment: @Pimgd - Wrong-sense of `<` to `>` appreciated, and fixed. No, I did not run the code... but what wrong advice?

Comment: That'd be the part where you combine the two methods. You're making the code more complicated to understand.

Comment: Ahh, I disagree there, but that's OK.

Comment: @Pimgd - care to discuss your [recent non-edits in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Type classify(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (!isSaneArguments(a, b, c) || !isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
        return Type.INVALID;
    }
    return classifyValidTriangle(a, b, c);
}
```

It's a classify function that takes a set of integers and if they're not all positive or they don't make a triangle then it's regarded as an invalid triangle.

Then you have an implicit else that works with a "valid" triangle.

It's basically begging for this addition:

```
public static boolean isValidTriangle(int a, int b, int c){
    return isSaneArguments(a, b, c) && isTriangle(a, b, c);
}

public static Type classify(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (!isValidTriangle(a, b, c)) {
        return Type.INVALID;
    }
    return classifyValidTriangle(a, b, c);
}
```

Additionally, for any three integers a b c, if a = 0 then a + b > c && a + c > b is false. Because that would imply that b > c and c > b. Thus I'd rename isTriangle to isValidTriangle, opposed to the function I described above.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the expression  `a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0`  redundant? given that if any of `a`, `b`, or `c` is `<= 0`, the expression  `(a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) > a`  would classify the triangle as invalid anyway.

@Pimgd mentioned above the case for when one of the sides is zero, but he didn't clarify if he would remove the expression for validating the sides are all `>0`.

```
 /**
 * Solution key for the triangle problem in Myers'
 * "The Art of Software Testing".
 * 
 * @author melvinperez
 * 
 */
public enum TriangleType {
    INVALID, SCALENE, EQUILATERAL, ISOSCELES;

    /**
     * This method take @param three values representing the lengths of the
     * sides of a triangle and @return the type of triangle they would form.
     */
    public static TriangleType classify(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
        if (sidesFormATriangle(a, b, c))
            if (allSidesAreEqual(a, b, c))
                return EQUILATERAL;
            else if (twoOfTheSidesAreEqual(a, b, c))
                return ISOSCELES;
            else
                return SCALENE;
        else
            return INVALID;
    }

    private static boolean twoOfTheSidesAreEqual(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a == b || b == c || c == a;
    }

    private static boolean allSidesAreEqual(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a == b && b == c;
    }

    /**
     * The sum of the lengths of any two sides must be greater than or equal to
     * the length of the remaining side. However, although valid, this
     * implementation considers the degenerate case (x + y = z) invalid.
     * 
     * @return True if the sum of the lengths of any two sides is greater than
     *         the length of the remaining side
     */
    private static boolean sidesFormATriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick detail I haven't seen in the other answers:

```
if (!isSaneArguments(a, b, c)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("All sides of a Triangle must be > 0");
}
```

First off, I don't really like the name `isSaneArguments`. But really, my point is that you shouldn't separate the validation logic from the message.

The information that failure of the validation means that either parameter was `<= 0` is information that belongs *inside* the validation method because the caller should actually not know what exactly happened in that method.

A common approach would be

```
public void doSomething( int a, int b ) {
    checkArgumentsArePositive( a, b );

    // Do awesome stuff
}

public void checkArgumentsArePositive( int... arguments ) {
    for( int argument : arguments ) {
        if( argument <= 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Argument must be positive, but found " + argument );
        }
    }
```

}

Of course, there are many other ways to do this as well.